# What does it mean when people are shown in green in the hospital?

Tags: disgaea

I overcame Eternal Winter... though only barely. Hell Pepper spam is bullshit. Anyway, this is my hospital bill, and Laharl is in... green?

[image]

What's up with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A name in green in the hospital means that your character has a status ailment. It can be [Deprave](http://disgaea.wikia.com/wiki/Deprave), [Amnesia](http://disgaea.wikia.com/wiki/Forget), [Paralysis](http://disgaea.wikia.com/wiki/Paralysis), [Poison](http://disgaea.wikia.com/wiki/Poison), or [Sleep](http://disgaea.wikia.com/wiki/Sleep).